# Inserting proxy settings in system tables is not working

Tags: android

I am able to browse internet after I set my proxy ip and port from `settings -> wireless network -> Mobile network -> Access Point name -> Telkila -> proxy`.But instead of setting proxy here if I try to insert a row having `values(99,'http_proxy','10.203.227.227:80')` as suggested http://www.anddev.org/emulator__internet_behind_proxy-t130.html without manually setting the proxy from `settings -> wireless network -> Mobile network -> Access Point name -> Telkila -> proxy`

I'm unable to browse the internet.Since I have to do proxy setting from the code itself, I have planned to connect to settings.db from my code and insert this record in system table from the code only.However this time I am writing the sql to insert the record in system table in sqlite3 prompt.Once I am successful in this then I write the code for db connectivity.But unfortunately I am not successful to browse the net after inserting the row in system table.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Arka