# Configuring proxy from code in Android app

Tags: android

I have a requirement like as following

```
if(condition){
//configure the proxy
}
```

Now I am able to browse the web from the emulator after I configure the proxy from

> settings -> wireless network -> Mobile network -> Access Point name -> Telkila -> proxy.

I came to know that proxy configuration can also be done by inserting (99,'http_proxy','<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>') in `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/settings.db.system` table. So I inserted the following row (99,'http_proxy','10.203.227.227:80'). But after inserting this I am unable to browse the web through the emulator.

My strategy was like inserting this row from my code. But this doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other way that I can configure proxy settings from code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting proxy settings in system tables is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472811/inserting-proxy-settings-in-system-tables-is-not-working)

Comment: Please do not repost the same question you've already asked. If the other post is not getting answers then you should consider re-wording it to make it clearer, or add a bounty to the question. Duplicate posts will just get closed.

Comment: please watch this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629644/how-can-you-set-the-http-proxy-programatically

Comment: @Kshetri Horrorgoogle I have already tried that post.That is not working.There are lots of post including one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380/proxy-with-android-emulator which says that inserting the record in the system table should work.However it is not working.